# drupal chat with trusted contact only drupal commons

Tags: 7, emails

I am integrating the Drupal chat with [Drupal commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons) module . Now its working .but my actual need is to integrate this with only for trusted contacts is it possible .

If yes means how I need to configure this ?

Comment: What do you mean by trusted contacts here ?

Comment: In drupal commons trusted contact section is there .Friends group and i am new to drupal .i searched a lot but i didn't find any solution for this .

Comment: @Sarabanan have you solved your issue ?

Comment: no nishant i mailed to your personal mail also . help me to do it